# How do I remove these icons on desktop?

Tags: desktop-apps

I have installed xfce4 via crouton and I have these things I want to remove but I can't.

I tried right clicking them but it didn't work there was no options.

[image: this is a pic of what I'm trying to remove*]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on an empty space on the desktop.
2. Click on **Desktop Settings**.
3. Go to the **Icons** tab.
4. In the **Default Icons** section *untick* the items you don't want to be visible.

This will remove the **volume** and the **File System** icons. Any other app startup icons can be deleted manually.

Comment: YOUR A LEGEND THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: You're welcome.